# How do I use AntiforgeryToken with dropzone.js and MVC 5 with Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I'm stuck at the moment trying to figure out how can I send the antiforgery token using Dropzone.js and vanilla javascript (no jQuery).

This is my initialization code at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone", { url: "/Media/AjaxUpload", maxFilesize: 10, addRemoveLinks: true, maxFiles: 1 });
        myDropzone.on("success", function (response) {
            //Do some personal stuff.
        });
        myDropzone.on("sending", function (xhr, formData) {
            formData["__RequestAntiForgeryToken"] = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[1].value
        });

    });
```

I have tried appending the token to no avail on Dropzone's sending event, even at the header. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you nearly nailed it there on the first go, Jose. The small mistake you made was missing an argument in the event handler function.

From the [Dropzone documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending):

> Called just before each file is sent. Gets the xhr object and the
>   formData objects as **second and third parameters**, so you can modify
>   them (for example to add a CSRF token) or add additional data.

The event arguments are actually `file, xhr, formData`, and if you include all three then you can manipulate the form successfully. The advantage of doing things this way is that there is no need to create a custom attribute, just use the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute.

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
    formData["__RequestAntiForgeryToken"] = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[1].value;
});
```

I have tested this with a slightly different implemetation than your's, and it works nicely.

Comment: For me using `formData.append("__RequestAntiForgeryToken", tokenElement)`also worked.

Comment: for me it works only with `formData.append(k,v)` not with `formData[k]= v`, and it has to be `__RequestVerificationToken` not `__RequestAntiForgeryToken`  (asp.net core 3)

Comment: `formData.append("__RequestVerificationToken")` works nicely, I needed to to use |`document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].defaultValue` on the client to get the token

Answer (score 6):

The way I ended up achieving this was through many suggestions at Stackoverflow. I created a special filter on MVC and passed the token via the headers. Like this:

Taking the idea from here: 
http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Updated-Anti-XSRF-Validation-for-ASP.NET-MVC-4-RC

I managed to send the token via dropzone's header:

The code ended up like this:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone", {
            url: "/Media/AjaxUpload", maxFilesize: 10, addRemoveLinks: true, maxFiles: 1,
            headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[1].value }
        });
```

I added "headers" to the Dropzone instantiation, and added the filter to MVC:

```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple= false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null,
                             httpContext.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
    }
}
```

Then apply to your controller:

```
 [ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult AjaxUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //Do Logic here!

        return Json("Success");
}
```

Comment: Dude, this is golden! A rare treasure indeed. Well done.

Comment: I'm finding that dropzone is setting __RequestVerificationToken to lowercase in the headers payload and MVC is failing.  Very strange...

Comment: Yep seen the same with latest dropzone, dropped it in favor of other development on the site. But getting to a beta release and I need to revisit the implementation of antiforgery